# how to add css to table consistently

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this simple website that adds and removes rows from a table. I have a two problems.The first one is whenever i add elements and them start deleting them my css style for my table is gone. Any idea how to fix it ? For example if i add 5rows and try to delete two of them then my style for all rows is gone. The second problem is how can i implement a `function counter` that will change the number of elements in the table and will keep track of them whenever someone removes or add new element. Here is my code:

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var author = document.getElementById("author");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function addToTable() {
  var radio = document.getElementsByName("content");
  var radio_selected;
  for (var a = 0; a < radio.length; a++) {
    if (radio[a].checked) {
      radio_selected =

        radio[a].value;
    }
  }
  output.innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + title.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + author.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + radio_selected + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='button' onclick='post(this);' id='post' value='Post'>" +
    "<input type='button' onclick='remove(this);' id='remove'value='Remove'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
}

function counter() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
  counter.innerHTML += 1;
}

function remove(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  var removed = document.getElementById("removed");

  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

}

function post(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  btn.parentNode.lastElementChild.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="Title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="Author">Author</label>
      <input type="text" id="author">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="content" id="contentlabel">Content type</label>
      <input type="radio" name="content" value="Free" class="content">Free
      <input type="radio" name="content" value="Paid" class="content">Paid
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addToTable(); counter();">
  </div>


  <div>
    <h1>Number of elements<span id="counterForElements">0</span></h1>

  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="output">
      <th style="width:40%;">Title</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Author</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Type</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Button</th>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Removed elements</h1>
    <table id="removed">

    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are adding an `<input>` with `id="post"` but IDs must be unique. Once you add more than one element with the same ID, you are breaking the rules of HTML and can't rely on the browser's behavior.

Comment: @kmoser i removed the id and tried with class same problem then i removed the class and its still not working

Comment: I ran your snippet and it all seems to work fine (I can add/delete/post without problem). When I post the row turns green and stay green even when I delete another row. Can you describe your exact problem again?

Comment: @E-telier But when you add and delete some rows and then add few more rows they dont have css they dont have border..

Comment: @itmemilan I tested it again (add/remove randomly) and I never encountered the border issue. What web browser do you use?

Comment: @E-telier mozilla firefox

Comment: @itmemilan There is indeed a **bug** with `border-collapse` in Firefox. I didn't find any easy fix for it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found what cause **the border issue in Firefox**.

Your output is set to the `<table>`, but you used `<th>` without `<thead>` nor `<th>`.

I simply added **those missing tags**, then I set the output to a new `<tbody>` tag.
It seems to work fine now.

```js
var title = document.getElementById("title");
var author = document.getElementById("author");
var output = document.getElementById("output");

function addToTable() {
  var radio = document.getElementsByName("content");
  var radio_selected;
  for (var a = 0; a < radio.length; a++) {
    if (radio[a].checked) {
      radio_selected =

        radio[a].value;
    }
  }
  output.innerHTML += "<tr>" + "<td>" + title.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + author.value + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + radio_selected + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + "<input type='button' onclick='post(this);' id='post' value='Post'>" +
    "<input type='button' onclick='remove(this);' id='remove'value='Remove'>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
}

function counter() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
  counter.innerHTML += 1;
}

function remove(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
  var removed = document.getElementById("removed");

  row.parentNode.removeChild(row);

}

function post(btn) {
  var row = btn.parentNode;
  row.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = "Green";
  btn.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  btn.parentNode.lastElementChild.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
}
```

```css
label {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}

table,
th,
td,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label for="Title">Title</label>
      <input type="text" id="title">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="Author">Author</label>
      <input type="text" id="author">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="content" id="contentlabel">Content type</label>
      <input type="radio" name="content" value="Free" class="content">Free
      <input type="radio" name="content" value="Paid" class="content">Paid
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addToTable(); counter();">
  </div>


  <div>
    <h1>Number of elements<span id="counterForElements">0</span></h1>

  </div>
  <div>
    <table>
    <thead>
    
      <th style="width:40%;">Title</th>
      <th style="width:40%;">Author</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Type</th>
      <th style="width:10%;">Button</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="output">
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Removed elements</h1>
    <table id="removed">

    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `counter()` function is not properly treating the `innerHTML` property as an integer. Here is a fix:

```js
function counter() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
  counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
}
```

Another way would be with a global variable:

```js
let counter = 0;

function counter() {
  var counter = document.getElementById("counterForElements");
  counter.innerHTML = ++counter;
}
```

If you want to keep track of removals, you would need to do so in `remove()`:

```
function remove(btn) {
  // ... existing code goes here
  counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
  // or:
  counter.innerHTML = --counter;
}
```

Another way would be to count the number of `<tr>` elements in the table and store that in `counter.innerHTML` every time you add or remove a row.